# JsonExtensionData create custom extension data

Tags: c#, json.net

I all,

I facing a problem where I cannot annotate the model with using newtonsoft [JsonExtensionData] without the annotation the result is :

```
{
    Prop1: value1,
    Prop2: value2,
    Prop3: {
       Key1: valuekey1,
       key2: valuekey2,
     }
}
```

but a need it to be:

```
{
    Prop1: value1,
    Prop2: value2,
    Key1: valuekey1,
    key2: valuekey2,
}
```

can i do this without using the annotation?

```
public class test1 { 
   public string Prop1{get;set;} 
   public string Prop2 {get;set} 
   public Dictionary<string,object> Prop3 {get;set;} 
}
```

Thanks in advance